# DJANGO: TypeError: CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'

Tags: python, django

Estoy intentando crear un usuario personalizado, he guardado los modelos sin ningún problema pero no puedo llegar a ejecutarlo con exito, al usar el comando **py manage.py createsuperuser** , me lanza el siguiente error y  no encuentro el 'email' al que se refiere:

**raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.**name**, kwarg))
TypeError: CustomUser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'**

ACLARO: mi app(Usuario) esta registrada en la settigns.py

y tambien :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Usuario.CustomUser'
```

**Aqui os dejo mi models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, UserManager
# Create your models here.

#PRUEBA DE MODELOS PARA USAURIO PERZONALIZADO

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    #THE FIELDS OF THE USER MODEL
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=250)
    PhoneNumber = models.IntegerField()
    User_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    User_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Objects = UserManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username +","+ self.Name +","+ self.Lastname +","+ self.Email +","+ str(self.PhoneNumber) 
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['Name', 'Lastname', 'Email', 'PhoneNumber']

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.User_admin

    
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, Name, Lastname, PhoneNumber, Email, password= None):
        if not Email:
            raise ValueError("Es obligatorio ingresar un correo")

        User = self.model(
            
            username = username,
            Name = Name,
            Lastname = Lastname,
            Email = self.normalize_email(Email)
            )
        User.set_password(password)
        User.save()
        return User

    def create_superuser(self, username, Name, Lastname, PhoneNumber, Email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            Email="",
            username = username,
            Name = Name,
            Lastname = Lastname,   
         )
        user.User_admin = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez sea porque tienes tu campo "Email" con la primera letra en mayúscula, el modelo de usuario de django lo tiene en miníscula y como estas heredando de este, puede que te de error por eso.

Ahora por otro lado, cuando heredas de AbstractBaseUser, tienes que reescribir todos los campos que tenía el modelo de django, lo cual no es apropiado, ya que para que vas a sobreescribir algo que ya está bien hecho, para eso podrias heredar de AbstractUser y de esa forma agregas mas campos que creas conveniente añadir al modelo de django y ya no tienes que sobreescribir todos sus campos.

Ahora tambíen podrias intentar especificar cual va a ser tu campo de Email con la propiedad EMAIL_FIELD, al igual que lo haces con USERNAME_FIELD para el nombre de usuario.

Comment: le voy a hechar un vistaso a ABASTRACTUSER, gracias por el consejo

Comment: ¿Cómo quedó esto? ¿Cómo se solucionó? Un saludo.